# std::coutとstd::wcoutを混在させると正しく出力されない

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
int main()
{
    std::setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "");
    std::wcout << L"あいうえお" << std::endl;
}
```

とすると、`あいうえお` と出力されます。

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
int main()
{
    std::setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "");
    std::cout << "あいうえお" << std::endl;
}
```

とすると、やはり`あいうえお` と出力されます。
ところが、

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
int main()
{
    std::setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "");
    std::cout << "あいうえお" << std::endl;
    std::wcout << L"あいうえお" << std::endl;
}
```

とすると

`あいうえお`
`あいうえお`

を期待していましたが

`あいうえお`
`BDFHJ`

と出力されます。

```
    std::wcout << L"あいうえお" << std::endl;
```

が正しく表示さなく、`BDFHJ`と出力されます。

そもそもstd::coutとstd::wcoutを混在させることはまれなので、さほど大きな問題とはかんじていないのですが、不思議な結果に驚いています。

**質問**
これは仕様通りの結果なのでしょうか？

環境は、
 Ubuntu14.04(x86_64)
 LANG="ja_JP.UTF-8"

g++ version 4.8.5
 clang++ version 3.4
で結果は同じでした。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[setlocale使用時の挙動について](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/8507/)
と同じ原因によります。

[c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) 言語仕様書 ISO/IEC 14882:1998 によれば

27.3.1 Narrow stream object の 3
`cout` は `stdout` に結び付けられる
27.3.2 Wide stream object の 3
`wcout` は `stdout` に結び付けられる

ので、あとはリンク先の情報にあるとおりでしょう。